# Changing button label from c# code-behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, button

I am sorry I can't solve what must be simple to everyone else even after reading so many posts.  Simply stated... I have an ASP webpage I created in VS2010 and when the user clicks the 'Send Email' button, I want to change the button either using JQuery then calling my code-behind to do the actual send.  Alternatively, I want the C# code behind to change the button text while it is in the process of sending so the user knows to hold on.

I am new to JQuery and still pretty new to C#.  My website is www. themilwaukeehandcenter.com.  If you click the contact us... this is where I want the code.   I have tried

```
$("ContactUsButton").click(function () {
      ContactUsLabel.Text = "Processing";
  });
```

on the main page.  I have also tried

```
   protected void ContactUsButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ContactUsLabel.Text = "Sending... Please Wait";
        ContactUsLabel.Refresh();
```

I know this should be simple but hours later.... reading so many posts later.... I feel no farther.  I can't quite figure out how the JQuery onclick and the ASP onclick interact.  I also don't know why C# flags the Refresh() as not valid.  Any help welcome.

I actually placed a ContactUsLabel on the form too when I couldn't get the ContactUsButton to do what I intended. I am too knew to understand what you mean by 'How have you declared your button, but this is the code that creates it:

```
<asp:Button ID="ContactUsButton" runat="server" 
     OnClick="ContactUsButton_Click" Text="Send Email" Width="120px"/> 
<asp:Label ID="ContactUsLabel" runat="server" Text="" Width="120px">
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Have you called it ContactUsButton one place and ContactUsLabel somewhere else?

Comment: How have you declared your button?

Comment: I actually placed a ContactUsLabel on the form too when I couldn't get the ContactUsButton to do what I intended.   I am too knew to understand what you mean by 'How have you declared your button, but this is the code that creates it:        <asp:Button  ID="ContactUsButton" runat="server" OnClick="ContactUsButton_Click" Text="Send Email" Width="120px"/>
        <asp:Label   ID="ContactUsLabel" runat="server" Text="" Width="120px"></asp:Label>

Comment: And thank you for taking interest in my question

Comment: The code is how you are declaring it :)

JQuery is running in the person's browser, and the .NET OnClick is running back at the server (so it has information sent from the browser to the server, and then it sends it back).

So they are useful in different scenarios.

Your question specifically asks "in C# code behind" - for me, just taking the Refresh line out worked. What behaviour are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WinForm Code:

```
<asp:button id="ContactUsButton" runat="server" onclick="ContactUsButton_Click" cssClass="myButton" text="Contact Us" />
```

On submit use the jQuery script to change button text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myButton').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('value', 'Processing...');
    });
});
```

View in fiddler: [view](http://jsfiddle.net/k4akhfad/1/)

Finally at the server side:

```
protected void ContactUsButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ContactUsButton.Text = "Thank You";         
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help from you both.  Creating the cssclass to then refer to in JQuery did the trick to change the label right away.  I am still learning why I need things like 'this', and the 'attr' rather than just doing $(.myButton).value="Processing..."

Comment: After the message is sent, I close the overlay div right away which is probably why the user doesn't get to see the 'sent' text.  That's o.k.    For the future.... is there a command word like 'Refresh' that can send updates to the browswer as my code behind is running?

Comment: No. You cannot do a "Refresh" from a c# code behind. To achieve that you have to make ajax calls to server.